# Is it possible to access other plugins from a plugin and change their values in gradle?

Tags: android, plugins, gradle, build.gradle

I want to use a build script for a android application. So I use "apply plugin: 'com.android.application'" in my build.gradle-file. Then I can use something like:

```
android{ <somestuff> }
```

Of cause there are dependencies and repository aswell. Since here it work's like a charm. But I want to use this multiple times, so I decide to put it in a extra script and done "apply from: ''". This work's aswell. Now I was going to write a plugin to do this stuff but it did not work. I can't tell my plugin to access the android{} object. Now my question is: Is it possible to access the objects from other plugins. (myPlugin have to access the com.android.application-Plugin) OR: How can I write a plugin which just add's the values of my script in the build.gradle. I tried so many thing's but nothing worked. Hope there is a solution!

Comment: What didn't work exactly? It should be possible.

Comment: How can you access the android plugin from a different plugin? So I can change their values!

Answer (score 1):

To get the plugin, you can use `project.plugins.findPlugin()`. You can use the name or the Java class as argument.

That will give you the plugin. Now don't expect this to work:

```
def android = project.plugins.findPlugin('android')
```

because `android{ <somestuff> }` means "find the extension `android` registered by someone and apply a closure to it. So the correct way to configure a plugin is to access the extension which it registers:

```
def android = def eclipse = project.extensions.findByName('android')
// You can also use project.extensions.findByType() if you know the Java class

android{ <somestuff will now work> }
```

You may also want to make sure this only happens when the plugin has been applied:

```
project.plugins.withId('android') { plugin ->
    def android = def eclipse = project.extensions.findByName('android')
    android{ <somestuff will now work> }
}
```

`withId` won't do anything until the plugin is applied. If it's already applied, it will execute the action immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Following Aaron's suggestion, I tried to configure `maven-publish` plugin by adding `repositories` to it. Unfortunately, accessing `publishing` extension as proposed caused following error:

> Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed

Probably the solution would work, if I didn't want user to specify part of configuration (`publications`) in Gradle DSL. I suppose however, that if I configure the extension from my plugin, user can no longer specify it in Gradle DSL.

I found solution in `MavenPublishPlugin` itself, as it applies and configures `PublishingPlugin` ([source](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v4.6.0/subprojects/maven/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/publish/maven/plugins/MavenPublishPlugin.java#L104)). The following code worked for me (Kotlin):

```
project.plugins.withId("maven-publish", { publishPlugin ->
    project.extensions.configure(PublishingExtension::class.java, { publishing ->
        publishing.repositories({ repoHandler ->
            repoHandler.maven({ repo ->
                repo.setUrl("someRepoUrl")
            })
        })
    })
})
```